When FaceID get error three times, and show alert, then can i remove 'Enter Passcode' option?
As title.
I want to remove 'Enter Passcode' this option.
Users just only click 'cancel verify'.
Or Apple won't let me do this kind of thing.
func doBiometry(completionHandler: @escaping(Bool) -> Void){

        let context = LAContext()
        var authError: NSError?

        if context.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: &authError) {
           
            context.evaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, localizedReason: (BundleLocalization.sharedInstance()!.localizedString(forKey: title, alter: nil)), reply: { (success, error) in

                if success{
                    completionHandler(true)
                }else{
                    completionHandler(false)
                }
            })
        }
    }



There is a way to remove this action. Add the line below before making canEvaluatePolicy:
let context = LAContext()
context.localizedFallbackTitle = "" //<- here


Use the localizedFallbackTitle property to set a title for the fallback button. When the property is nil—as it is by default—the user sees an appropriate default title, like “Use Passcode”. Otherwise, provide a localized string that’s short and clear.


To eliminate the fallback option, set the fallback title to an empty string. This hides the button from the interface.

Check this documentation about localizedfallbacktitle for more information.

Nothing tricky about it. It's the intended mechanism to remove the fallback button (as per Apple's documentation)

Oh, I missed one single line in the documentation. Thanks for pointed out. I edited the answer.
